# How to pass a value from HTML to CSS

Tags: html, css, jsp, sass

I want to change the theme colour based on theme name that is available in JSP page, How can I pass a variable that contain theme name from JSP to CSS file.

Comment: `<style><%if(someThemeColor){%> .dark { .... }</style><%}else{%>.dark { .... }<%}%>`

Comment: or

`<style rel="stylesheet" href="<%=someTheme%>.css" />`

Answer (score 2):

you can "pass" the value from the inline HTML to the CSS by having something like this:

**index.html**

```
<div style="--main-color: red;">RED</div>
```

**style.css**

```
div { background-color: var(--main-color); }
```